# Python isspace function

Tags: python, python-3.x, isspace

I'm having difficulty with the isspace function.  Any idea why my code is wrong and how to fix it?

Here is the problem:
Implement the get_num_of_non_WS_characters() function. get_num_of_non_WS_characters() has a string parameter and returns the number of characters in the string, excluding all whitespace.

Here is my code:

```
def get_num_of_non_WS_characters(s):

    count = 0
    for char in s: 
        if char.isspace():
            count = count + 1  
        return count
```

Comment: You are returning from your funciton on the first iteration, if that indentation is correct...

Comment: Two things: `if not char.isspace()` and un-indent the return statement. You're currently (if the indentation of `return` is fixed) return the number of whitespace characters.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You want *non* whitespace, so you should use `not`

```
def get_num_of_non_WS_characters(s):
    count = 0
    for char in s:
        if not char.isspace():
            count += 1
    return count

>>> get_num_of_non_WS_characters('hello')
5
>>> get_num_of_non_WS_characters('hello  ')
5
```

For completeness, this could be done more succinctly using a generator expression

```
def get_num_of_non_WS_characters(s):
    return sum(1 for char in s if not char.isspace())
```

Comment: `return sum(not char.isspace() for char in s)`?

Answer (score 1):

As an alternative you could also simple do:

```
def get_num_of_non_WS_characters(s):
    return len(''.join(s.split()))
```

Then

```
s = 'i am a string'
get_num_of_non_WS_characters(s)
```

will return `10`

This will also remove tabs and new line characters:

```
s = 'i am a string\nwith line break'
''.join(s.split())
```

will give

```
'iamastringwithlinebreak'
```

Answer (score 1):

A shorter version of @CoryKramer answer:

```
def get_num_of_non_WS_characters(s):
    return sum(not c.isspace() for c in s)
```

Answer (score 0):

I would just use n=s.replace(" " , "") and then len(n).
Otherwise I think you should increase the count after the if statement and put a continue inside it.

Comment: `str.isspace()` doesn't just check for " ".

Comment: That will only count the number of chars that aren't equal to the space char, it doesn't exclude other whitespace from the count, like tabs, newlines, etc.